# How can I display more than one image after uploading several at a time? JS

Tags: javascript, image, display

I'm working on an image organizer that i want to put through google image descriptions. At the moment I'm trying to upload all images at once to the server and display them, for some reason it's only displaying the last choice.

HTML

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' multiple onchange="readURL(this);"/>
<div id="images-container"></div>
<label><strong>(Image will display above)</strong></label>
```

CSS

```
#blah {
    display: block;
}

img {
    width:100%;
}
.picContainer {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block
}
```

JS

```
 $("input").change(function(e) {

 for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

    var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

     var div = document.createElement("div");
     var img = document.createElement("img");
     div.className = "picContainer";
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function() {
         img.src = reader.result;
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     div.appendChild(img);
     //$("input").after(div);
     var container = document.getElementById("images-container");
     container.appendChild(div);
} });
```

Comment: where is your readURL() function. Upload the code for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This heppens becouse of [variable hoisting in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)

The compiler rewrites your code so it will look like that:

```
$("input").change(function(e) {
 var i, file, div, img, container;
 for (i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

    file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

     div = document.createElement("div");
     img = document.createElement("img");
     div.className = "picContainer";
     reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function() {
         img.src = reader.result;
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     div.appendChild(img);
     //$("input").after(div);
     container = document.getElementById("images-container");
     container.appendChild(div);
} });
```

what that means for you, is that in the function

```
reader.onloadend = function() {
    img.src = reader.result;
}
```

the reader and the img variable always equal to the last one (even in the one that was initialized first)

You should probably use a function creator defined before the loop like that:

```
$("input").change(function(e) {
 function initOnReaderLoaded(img, reader){
    return function(){
        img.src = reader.result;
    }
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

    var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

     var div = document.createElement("div");
     var img = document.createElement("img");
     div.className = "picContainer";
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = initOnReaderLoaded(img, reader);
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     div.appendChild(img);
     //$("input").after(div);
     var container = document.getElementById("images-container");
     container.appendChild(div);
} });
```

Comment: Wow Max, thank you so much for the explanation. I'm still in my diapers here and this was super helpful! I wonder if I could trouble you with another query...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your img element inside the reader onload.

fiddle here:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

// Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

  // Only process image files.
  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();

  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
    };
  })(f);

  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
 }
}

 document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish3x3/37yz93rd/1/)